# Index position of the smallest number in the array

Tags: java

I have a question about return the index position of the smallest number in the array. I picked out 3 answers from 5 answer were given that I provided below. I think one of them might possibly be correct. However, I quite don't understand the code very much, so I'm looking for an explanation how they work.

A

```
public int min(int[] a) {
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] <  a[min]) {
            min = i;
        }
    }
    return a[i];
}
```

B

```
public int min(int[] a) {
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] <  a[min]) {
            min = i;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

C

```
public int min(int[] a) {
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] <  a[min]) {
            min = i;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: "I provided 3 answers below that I think they're possibly true" and why should they be true? The first two don't even compile correctly (apart from the obvious `,` typo in `int i = 1; i < a.length, i++`). And what they do can be easily tested. Have you tried testing them?

Comment: No I have not. I've been only trying to trace the code in order to understand the code. I can't understand the code that's why I need help

Comment: try running the code with print statements or use debugger to see what is happening.

Comment: So I edited the question. Those 3 solutions above, I picked them out from a combination of 5 solutions that I think they might be true or might be not, in my opinion.

Comment: The essence of learning to program is to develop that curiosity that makes you try things yourself. Be ready to sit down and run experiments for hours. In the long run, asking for explanations like you do here **slows** you down. Instead: run your code. Think up example arrays, then try to "execute" each method mentally on a piece of paper. Then run it, and use print statements to look at intermediate results. Don't ask for explanations when can find the answers yourself easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty straight forward.. you are looking for the **smallest index**.
Imagine array `a` has 3 elements.

A

```
public int min(int[] a) {
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length, i++) {
        if (a[i] <  a[min]) {
            min = i;
        }
    }
    return a[i];    //returning value. Wrong!
                    //you are searching for the index, not value isnt' it?
}
```

B

```
public int min(int[] a) {
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length, i++) {
        if (a[i] <  a[min]) {
            min = i;
        }
    }
    return i;    //returning i which only exist in for-loop scope. Wrong!
}
```

C

```
public int min(int[] a) {                   //assume a has 3 elements
    int min = 0;                            //for storing smallest index
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length, i++) {    //loop index 1,2
        if (a[i] <  a[min]) {               //if current array value < current smallest value
            min = i;                        //store new found smallest index
        }
    }
    return min;                             //returning min, the smallest index 
}
```

If `min` is not updated through the looping, it means index 0 (default value of min) holds the smallest value. Option C will be the correct answer.

Comment: Your remark regarding AIOOBE is wrong, mind that the abort condition is `<`, not `<=`. I also wonder why you correctly complain about the out-of-scope `i` in code B, but not in code A?

Comment: So do you think instead of i < a.length, i < = a.length would be the right answer here?

Comment: @Nin No, `i <= a.length` is wrong and _will_ cause the exception user3437460 mentioned.

Comment: @Tom In MCQ, we go by elimination of incorrect answers, for option A either `i` being out of for-loop scope or not returning the index, we will eliminate it as the incorrect option. For the AIOOBE, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The first code will give an error (Index out of bound exception)because at the end of for loop your " i " will be equal to the length of array and you are returning a[i] so this solution is completely wrong. The second code will return the length of array so it is also wrong solution. The third code that you have entered will return the index of smallest value. So the solution is correct.

Comment: Would you mind explain more about the first code? Why does it return the value of smallest index? I want to understand the code rather than just the solution

Comment: Oh sorry tom. Yeah you are right about the first code. I thought that the first code is returning a[min]